# How to handle a corner when using an L schluter edge?

Tags: backsplash

We're doing a backsplash and want a finished edge in certain places.

The big box hardware store told us about Schluter edges.

We got an L- shaped one so the edge is basically flat. It's also made of metal.

[image: schulter]

However there will be some corners. If we use 2 pieces to make the corner, the corner will be really sharp. I can't find corner pieces for a rounded transition (or at least a less sharp corner) - CORRECTION...I found pieces for the corners but they are $20 a pop.

Is there a cheaper way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean miter cut does indeed leave a very sharp corner. Since these are mill-finish, you can very lightly file or sand the resulting edge, just so it's not going to cut skin. You don't want to take so much that it's visually rounded.

If that's not acceptable, the only other idea I have is to bevel the corners of your backsplash slightly using two 22-1/2* angles, leaving a small flat where the original corner was. This does result in a very different look, though... almost a ranch-style effect.

Update: If you were to cut away the entire base flange for a short distance, you could probably bend the remaining face into a round corner. You'd have to experiment a bit to get something that doesn't tear. Aluminum seems soft, but it doesn't handle sharp bends like steel does.